# STRTOK getting the middle name like another column

Tags: c, csv, parsing, strtok

I would like someone to help me with my problem:

- when I go to parse the csv file, people who have two names the middle name counts them as two columns

code:

```
void getStructValues(FILE* fp, studente stud[]) {

    char buffer[1024];
    int row = 0, col = 0, i = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp)) {
        col = 0;
        row++;

        char* value = strtok(buffer, ",");

        while(value) {
            switch(col) {
                case 0:
                    printf("First Column: %s\n", value);
                    strcpy(stud[i].last_name, value);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("Second Column: %s\n", value);
                    strcpy(stud[i].name, value);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Third Column: %s\n", value);
                    //strcpy(stud[i].gender, value);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("Fourth Column: %s\n", value);
                    //strcpy(stud[i].province, value);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("Fifth Column: %s\n", value);
                    //value = atoi(value);
                    //stud[i].n_exam = value;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf("Sixth Column: %s\n", value);
                    value = atoi(value);
                    stud[i].average = (int) value;
                    break;
            }
            value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
            col++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The CSV File:

```
BARLET,ELISABET GIOVA,F,NO,14,18
```

Expected OutPut:

```
First Column: BARLET
Second Column: ELISABT GIOVA
Third Column: F
Foruth Column: NO
Fifth Column: 14
Sixth COlumn: 18
```

MTy OutPut:

```
First Column: BARLET
Second Column: ELISABT 
Third Column: GIOVA
Foruth Column: F
Fifth Column: NO
Sixth COlumn: 14
```

The problem seems to exist when it takes the name and splits it in two (creating that column) (try to use only "," as a separator the result is the same)
Anyone know how to help me?

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Your second call to `strtok()` splits on both spaces and commas.  If you only want to split on commas, don't include the space in the delimiters.

Answer (score 6):

In the `while` you have `value = strtok(NULL, ", ");`

Notice the space after the `,`. It means `strtok` will try to split by any of `,` or   (space).

Comment: It wansn't only that, but it helped a lot, thanks! (the problems it was when at the end I nullifing the STRTOK function (with `value = STRTOK(NULL, ", ");`))